# Is it possible to get a free 15 day visa upon arrival at Hanoi airport?

Tags: visas, australian-citizens, vietnam, maltese-citizens

I read somewhere its possible to get a free 15 day Vietnam visa upon arrival at Hanoi airport as long as I show proof I'm leaving Vietnam within 15 days, which I am.
I'm flying to Hanoi from Kuala Lumpur, will I have a problem boarding my flight with no Vietnam visa or visa approval letter?

I have 2 passports, Malta and Australia.

Comment: Disagree on the duplicate. The question is different and the answers don't fully explain the situation either.

Comment: To explain the "difference" in the question - the currently marked "duplicate" is asking about "e-visas" which do not exist, but are probably a confsion regardingthe pre-approved visa on arrival. This question is asking about VOA, but appears to be actually a result of misunderstading the vietnamese visa waiver system.

Answer (score 3):

No, that isn't true.

Vietnam doesn't operate a true "Visa on Arrival" system. In additional, all visas for Vietnam have a fee. Some nationalities can enter without a visa, paying nothing and being allowed to remain for 15 days, [but neither of your nationalities s are included in that list](http://lanhsuvietnam.gov.vn/Lists/BaiViet/B%C3%A0i%20vi%E1%BA%BFt/DispForm.aspx?List=dc7c7d75-6a32-4215-afeb-47d4bee70eee&ID=306). Your options for entering Vietnam are:

- Apply for a visa in advance from the relevant Vietnamese embassy. [This page from the Vietnamese government may be helpful.](http://visa.mofa.gov.vn/Homepage.aspx)
- Apply for a "pre-approved Visa on Arrival", where you initally pay a fee to a third party company (who provide an approval letter), then pay at a desk at Ho Chi Minh, Hanoi or Da Nang airport (US dollars only) to receive your actual visa. This service is not available at other points of arrival in to Vietnam. [You can find out more on this Tripadvisor thread.](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Travel-g293921-c148049/Vietnam:Faq.Visa.On.Arrival.Voa.html) Note that while there are many legitimate agencies who can provide this service, there are also a lot of scammers.

You will not be able to board a flight to Vietnam without either a valid Visa, or a stamped and approved invitation letter for the day you are arriving.

Comment: I also read this https://www.tripadvisor.com.ph/ShowTopic-g293924-i8595-k9287625-15_days_visa_exemption-Hanoi.html

Comment: @davoz The people asking at the start of that thread have UK passports. You don't. Neither Australian note Maltese citizens are granted the visa exemption, as you can see from my links.

Comment: I have heard the warning "there are a lot of scammers" (which is true about pretty any subject around SEA), but have not run into anyone who has been scammed in this particular way -- by comparison with Cambodia, where the visa-scam is almost built into the entry process.